# Tabularx: columns with different widths

Tags: tabularx, width

My code can be found below.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{SelfArx} % Document font size and equations flushed left

\usepackage[font=small]{caption}

% New commands
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{NS}

% Load packages
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COLUMNS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.55cm} % Distance between the two columns of text
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.75pt} % Width of the border around the abstract
```

...

```
\begin{table}[hbt]
\caption{Fold changes in relaxation parameters in the dorsal muscle and lumbar(/-osacral) IVDs. \\
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X*{2}{p{0.7cm}} X*{7}{p{0.9cm}}}
\toprule[1.5pt]
                              &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{Dorsal}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\head{IVD}}               \\
                                                            &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{muscle}}               \\ \cmidrule{3-4} \cmidrule{5-9}
           &                   &       1     & 2     & L3-L4 & L4-L5 & L5-L6 & L6-L7 & L7-S1 \\ \midrule
         & t2/t1 & 0.99$^*$  & 1.24 & 0.64  & 1.05$^*$  & 1.53  & 1.52  & 2.45  \\
\head{T$_{1\rho}$} & t3/t2 & 1.3   & 0.88 & 2.61  & 1.16  & 1.07$^*$  & 1.03$^*$  & 0.7   \\
         & t3/t1 & 1.29  & 1.1$^*$  & 1.68  & 1.22  & 1.63  & 1.56  & 1.72  \\ \midrule
         & t2/t1 & 1.18  & 1.05 & 1.07$^*$  & 1.05$^*$  & 0.83  & 1.43  & 1.32  \\
\head{T$_2$}       & t3/t2 & 0.87  & 1.03 & 0.66  & 0.67  & 0.94$^*$  & 0.69  & 0.67  \\
         & t3/t1 & 1.02$^*$  & 1.08 & 0.71  & 0.7   & 0.78  & 0.99$^*$  & 0.88 \\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab:lbl}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I want to get a table that fits within the width of a column (2 columns on a page, spacing between columns = 0.55 cm, column width ~= 7.925 cm).

I want to decrease the distance from the text to the cell borders for the first two columns, and have the same cell size for the 7 following columns.

[image: Just copied this from answer below]
[image: Result after using solution propsed below]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There is no `\begin{document}` in your example ;-) And where can we find the `SelfArx` class?

Comment: I'd never use `tabularx` for numeric data, it is designed to change the linebreaking width of paragraphs of _text_.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} % Document font size and equations flushed left
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\begin{document} 

\noindent\hrulefill a line\hrulefill% to show the linewidth
\def\N{\phantom{0}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l l c c *5l @{}}
\toprule[1.5pt]
                              &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{Dorsal}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\head{IVD}} \\
                                                            &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{muscle}}               \\ \cmidrule{3-4} \cmidrule{5-9}
           &                   &       1     & 2     & L3-L4 & L4-L5 & L5-L6 & L6-L7 & L7-S1 \\ \midrule
         & t2/t1 & 0.99\rlap{$^*$}  & 1.24 & 0.64  & 1.05$^*$  & 1.53  & 1.52  & 2.45  \\
\head{T$_{1\rho}$} & t3/t2 & 1.3\N   & 0.88 & 2.61  & 1.16  & 1.07$^*$  & 1.03$^*$  & 0.7   \\
         & t3/t1 & 1.29  & 1.1\N\rlap{$^*$}  & 1.68  & 1.22  & 1.63  & 1.56  & 1.72  \\ \midrule
         & t2/t1 & 1.18  & 1.05 & 1.07$^*$  & 1.05$^*$  & 0.83  & 1.43  & 1.32  \\
\head{T$_2$}       & t3/t2 & 0.87  & 1.03 & 0.66  & 0.67  & 0.94$^*$  & 0.69  & 0.67  \\
         & t3/t1 & 1.02\rlap{$^*$}  & 1.08 & 0.71  & 0.7   & 0.78  & 0.99$^*$  & 0.88 \\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify my intentions

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: Should I use \begin{table} before \begin{center}? It still runs through my text :( (see second figure in question above)

Comment: Use `\begin{table}\centering\caption{...}  <the tabular>  \end{table}`